# Automapper exception started showing suddenly

Tags: c#, exception, mapping, automapper, class-library

I have a class library and in one of the classes I am using Automapper. In constructor, I am doing like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ItemSummary, Sponsor>();
            cfg.CreateMap<AdminService.SponsorshipType, SponsorshipType>();
        });
```

Where ItemSummary is being returned by a webservice and it returns an array of ItemSummary objects i.e. ItemSummary[]. 
Sponsor is my domain model and contains exact same props (with same data types too).
Then, in one of the methods where I fetch ItemSummary, I use this mapping like this:

```
var sponsors = _service.GetItems(_accessKey);
List<Sponsor> sponsorsList = new List<Sponsor>();
sponsorsList = Mapper.Map<List<Sponsor>>(sponsors);
return sponsorsList;
```

This code was working just fine until about 15 minutes ago. But now I get this exception:

```
[AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
ItemSummary -> Sponsor
Admin.Service.PlanOfficeAdminService.ItemSummary ->
Admin.Core.Models.Sponsors.Sponsor]
lambda_method(Closure , ItemSummary , Sponsor , ResolutionContext ) +73
AutoMapper.ResolutionContext.Map(TSource source, TDestination destination) +206
lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext ) +194

[AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
ItemSummary[] -> List`1
Admin.Service.AdminService.ItemSummary[] -> 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Admin.Core.Models.Sponsor, Admin.Core ...
```

What could have gone wrong suddenly? There have been no changes in this class anywehere else so no, there is nothing in the class somewhere that could have broken it.

Comment: The message is simple no mapping for `POAItemSummary -> Sponsor`, you have mapping for `ItemSummary -> Sponsor` and it looks like service is returning that `POA` class.

Comment: No. Actually that POA prefix is a typo. So the object is actually called ItemSummary. I have edited the exception message so now it corresponds to actual one i.e. without typo

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Someone had introduced a parameterized constructor in the domain model which AutoMapper does not seem to like at all.